# Romberg doesn't work with my function i python

Tags: python

i have a problem with my Code. Both Codes work fine seperated, but if I combine them i get the 'float objekt is not callable' error in line 111, 97, 87, 105. I am not a programmer (physicist) so i would apreiate your help. I beleave it is probably a stupid mistake.

Here comes the Code, if you need additional information, just ask.

Thanks.

```
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def V_eff(r,m,l):
    GM = 3.9860042e14
    return -GM*m/r+l**2/(2*m*r**2)

def EminusVeff(r,m,l,E):
    return E-V_eff(r,m,l)

E = -1.2e10
m = 1000
l1 = 68.8e12
l2 = 57.3e12
l3 = 81.35e12
xmin = 1
xmax = 4e7

xdata = numpy.linspace(xmin,xmax,1000)

plt.plot(xdata, -EminusVeff(xdata, 1000, l3, E), label='{0:.3e}'.format(l3))
plt.plot(xdata, -EminusVeff(xdata, 1000, l1, E), label='{0:.3e}'.format(l1))
plt.plot(xdata, -EminusVeff(xdata, 1000, l2, E), label='{0:.3e}'.format(l2))
plt.xlabel("r")
plt.ylabel(r'$V_\mathrm{eff} - E$')
plt.ylim(-0.14e11,0.2e11)
plt.xlim(0.3e7,4e7)
plt.legend(title="L")
plt.hlines(0, xmin, xmax, lw=0.5)

def regulaFalsi(func, x0, x1, args=()):
    epsilon = 1
    maxIterationen = 100
    iterationen = 0
    xArray = numpy.array([])
    y0 = func(x0, *args)
    y1 = func(x1, *args)
    if (y0*y1 > 0):
        return numpy.nan, -1
    if (x0 > x1):
        x2 = x0
        x0 = x1
        x1 = x2
    x2 = (x0*func(x1, *args) - x1*func(x0, *args))/(func(x1, *args) - func(x0, *args))
    xArray = numpy.append(xArray, x1)
    xArray = numpy.append(xArray, x2)
    while (abs(func(x2, *args)) >= epsilon): 
        y0 = func(x0, *args)
        y2 = func(x2, *args)
        if (y0*y2 > 0):
            x0 = x2 
        else:
            x1 = x2 
        x2 = (x0*func(x1, *args) - x1*func(x0, *args))/(func(x1, *args) - func(x0, *args)) 
        iterationen += 1
        if (iterationen > maxIterationen):
            return x2, -1 
        xArray = numpy.append(xArray, x2)
    return xArray[-1], iterationen

def r_min_max_analytisch(m,l,E):
    GM = 3.9860042e14
    p = (GM*m)/(E)
    q = - l**2/(2*E*m)
    r1 = -p/2-numpy.sqrt((p/2)**2 - q)
    r2 = -p/2+numpy.sqrt((p/2)**2 - q)
    if r1 < r2:
        return r1,r2
    else:
        return r2,r1
    
print("l1 analytisch: ", '{0:.0f} {1:.0f}'.format(*r_min_max_analytisch(m,l1,E)))
print("l1 numerisch : ",'{0:.0f}'.format(*regulaFalsi(EminusVeff, 7e6, 8e6, (m,l1,E))), \
      '{0:.0f}'.format(*regulaFalsi(EminusVeff, 2e7, 3e7, (m,l1,E))))

print("l2 analytisch: ", '{0:.0f} {1:.0f}'.format(*r_min_max_analytisch(m,l2,E)))
print("l2 numerisch : ",'{0:.0f}'.format(*regulaFalsi(EminusVeff, 4e6, 9e6, (m,l2,E))), \
      '{0:.0f}'.format(*regulaFalsi(EminusVeff, 2e7, 3e7, (m,l2,E))))

print("l3 analytisch: ", '{0:.0f} {1:.0f}'.format(*r_min_max_analytisch(m,l3,E)))
print("l3 numerisch : ", '{0:.0f}'.format(*regulaFalsi(EminusVeff, 1.6e7, 1.65e7, (m,l3,E))), \
      '{0:.0f}'.format(*regulaFalsi(EminusVeff, 1.65e7, 1.75e7, (m,l3,E))))


def Trapez(f, a, b, n):
    h = (b - a) / n
    x = a
    In = f(a)
    for k in range(1, n):
        x  = x + h
        In += 2*f(x)

    return (In + f(b))*h*0.5

def romberg(f, a, b, p):   
    I = np.zeros((p, p))
    for i in range(0, p):
        I[i, 0] = Trapez(f, a, b, 2**i)
        for j in range(0, i):
            I[i, j+1] = (4**(j+1) * I[i, j] - I[i-1, j]) / (4**(j+1) - 1)

        print(I[i,0:i+1]) 
    return I
    
def func(r):
    phi = 1/(r**2*np.sqrt(((2*m)/l1**2)(EminusVeff(r,m,l1,E))))
    return phi

              
              
p_rows = 10             
I = romberg(func, 7742086, 25474616, p_rows)
solution = I[p_rows-1, p_rows-1]
print(solution)
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer that solved your question :) Also, there are no stupid mistakes. Next time, describes exactly what you did - you mention two programs that you merged together, but we can't know which is which. Also, if you use line numbers, make sure to include them in the code, or better yet, mark these lines in your code with comments `# like this`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into your `func` method:

```
phi = 1 / (r ** 2 * np.sqrt(((2 * m) / l1 ** 2)(EminusVeff(r, m, l1, E))))
#                                             ^^
```

There are two expressions without an operator.
This means: Call (the result of) `(r ** 2 * np.sqrt(((2 * m) / l1 ** 2)` with the argument `EminusVeff(r, m, l1, E)`.

Probably you want to multiply here, for that you have to add the `*` explicitly.